# ckeditor yellow buttons

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed ckeditor module for drupal 7.
Whenever any drupal form loads up, it comes up with yellow ckeditor buttons. 
I have checked the configuration page to hide the yellow background of ckeditor ,but there's ain't any settings.
[image]

So how can I hide this yellow background color. Is this CKEDITOR theme or just configurable?
Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: It's probably a stylesheet issue. What theme are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Configurable. Go to

> Admin -> Configuration -> CKEditor

And Edit the relevant profile in the text formats.(In your Case choose edit the fullhtml) Choose 
**Editor Appearance**
and there will be a Drop down to choose **User Interface Color**, Select **CKEditor Default**. If its already default then there must be some CSS override.

Comment: tks ..that did solved my problem.